# Examples of Kafka Rest

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Are there any good examples of the producer and consumer groups using the Kafka rest api in Java. Im not looking for simpleconsumer or kafka client examples of the producer and consumer. Any help is apprreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sample Rest API (Rest Proxy) code from Confluent. 
**Unfortunately not in Java but in Python. :(**
I had to type it, so it might contain some misspelling. I hope this helps you a little bit.

**( Producer using REST API written in Python )**

```
import requests
import base64
import json

url = "http://restproxy:8082/topics/my_topic"
headers = {
    "Content-Type" : "application/vnd.kafka.binary.v1 + json",
}
# Create one or more messages
payload = {"records":
       [{
           "key":base64.b64encode('firstkey'),
           "value":base64.b64encode('firstvalue'),
       }],
}
# Send the message
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
if r.status_code != 200:
   print("Status Code: " + str(r.status_code))
   print(r.text)
```

**(Consumer using Rest API written in Python)**

```
import requests
import base64
import json
import sys

#Base URL for interacting with REST server
baseurl = "http://restproxy:8082/consumers/group1"

#Create the Consumer instance
print("Creating consumer instance")
payload {
    "format": "binary",
}
headers = {
    "Content-Type" : "application/vnd.kafka.v1+json",
}
r = requests.post(baseurl, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

if r.status_code !=200:
    print("Status Code: " + str(r.status_code))
    print(r.text)
    sys.exit("Error thrown while creating consumer")

# Base URI is used to identify the consumer instance
base_uri = r.json()["base_uri"]

#Get the messages from the consumer
headers = {
    "Accept" : "application/vnd.kafka.binary.v1 + json",
}

# Request messages for the instance on the Topic
r = requests.get(base_uri + "/topics/my_topic", headers = headers, timeout =20)

if r.status_code != 200: 
    print("Status Code: " + str(r.status_code))
    print(r.text)
    sys.exit("Error thrown while getting message")

# Output all messages
for message in r.json():
    if message["key"] is not None:
        print("Message Key:" + base64.b64decode(message["key"]))
    print("Message Value:" + base64.b64decode(message["value"]))

# When we're done, delete the consumer
headers = {
    "Accept" : "application/vnd.kafka.v1+json",
}

r = requests.delete(base_uri, headers=headers)

if r.status_code != 204: 
    print("Status Code: " + str(r.status_code))
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: How can I remove record from here to send data like
{"Key1" : "value1", "key2": "value2"}

Answer (score 0):

its better to implement producer and consumer then integrate rest API for producer and consumer.

```
producer(){
//your implementation for producer
}

consumer(){
//your implementation for consumer
}
```

REST API:

```
@POST
restProducer(){
producer();
}

@GET
restConsumer(){
consumer();
}
```

--or else

try to leverage confluent implemented REST API

http://docs.confluent.io/1.0/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html